# trouble rendering equations on wordpress.com

Tags: latex, blogs

I tried to incorporate some equations into a wordpress blog entry.  No special installation, just using the version of mathjax Wordpress comes with.

My paragraph reads

> This action is invariant under conformal symmetries of the worldsheet
>   $latex  z \to z + \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty  \epsilon_n z^{n+1}  $ , where $latex z$ 
>   parameterizes the worldsheet.  In 2 dimensions, the conformal group is especially large and > there are infinitely many generators $latex  \l_n: z \to z +  \epsilon_n z^{n+1} $ .

Both equations give a "formula does not parse".  Only the "z" renders correctly.  If I put this into a latex document, the formula compile.  Can you explain?

The [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-latex/faq/) page gives hints, but does not resolve my problem.  The hints on the page do work.

Comment: What happens if you used the Wordpress Shortcode Syntax instead?

Comment: Do the examples given on the FAQ page you link above work in your blog?

Comment: I managed to trick Wordpress into rendering my equations.  Editing in HTML mode rather than Visual mode seems to work

Comment: Ah, the old "what you see isn't necessarily what you get" bug... :-)

Comment: This is such a good answer, you should post it as such.  It's totally within the spirit and letter of the stackoverflow guidelines.